# Posts not showing

Tags: loop

I have created a real estate theme, and for each property there is a property listing expiry date after which the property no longer shows on the site. Each property is a custom Properties post type. The code I use to only use live properties is;

```
function live_properties_only( $query ) {

    if ( ! is_main_query() ) {

        $today = date('Ymd');
        $meta_query = array (
            'post_type'      => 'properties',
            'meta_query' => array(
                    'key'       => 'date_listing_expires',
                    'compare'   => '>',
                    'value'     => $today,
                ),
        );

    $query->set('meta_query',$meta_query);

    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'live_properties_only' );
```

This is in the functions.php file, the only problem is that is prevents regular blog posts from showing. How can I resolve this so blog posts show and only un-expired properties also show.

Comment: Try adding `wp_reset_query();` after your if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to check if you are in the `properties` post type archive before to manipulate the query, so it doesn't affect to other archives.

Also, you need to check if the actual `$query` is the main query, so other queries are not affected (the function `is_main_query()` does a different thing; it doesn't check actual query; if you turn DEBUG on, you will get a message in the logs saying you are doing it wrong by using `is_main_query()` in `pre_get_posts` action). Finally, you probably want to exclude the query manipulation in admin side:

```
function live_properties_only( $query ) {

    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'properties' ) && ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        $today = date('Ymd');
        $meta_query = array (
            'meta_query' => array(
                    'key'       => 'date_listing_expires',
                    'compare'   => '>',
                    'value'     => $today,
                ),
        );

    $query->set('meta_query',$meta_query);

    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'live_properties_only' );
```

PD: comparing dates in meta fields should use YYYY-MM-DD format (Y-m-d for PHP `date()` function); then you can set the parameter `'type' => DATE` and you will be doing a date comparison in the way it has been tested; other methods can work but `WP_Query` has not been tested with them (obviously, the meta fields values need to be stored in this format as well):

```
        $today = date('Y-m-d');
        $meta_query = array (
            'meta_query' => array(
                    'key'       => 'date_listing_expires',
                    'compare'   => '>',
                    'value'     => $today,
                    'type'      => 'DATE'
                ),
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are only querying only for posts of the type 'properties.' I'm not 100% sure, but removing the post_type line *may* resolve this. I hope this helps :)

```
$meta_query = array (
            'meta_query' => array(
                    'key'       => 'date_listing_expires',
                    'compare'   => '>',
                    'value'     => $today,
                ),
        );
```